# what it the find list error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tyed get with the method `$this>model->find()` an array with ids of my model  that have this form:

```
Array ( [0] => 2,  [1] => 3)  (value are the IDs)
```

and I try `$this->model->find('list')` I thought that would work too but for some strange reason I have done:

```
$this->model->find('list',array('recursive' => -1  ,'fields' => array('model.type_id'),'conditions'=>$cond));
```

and the query result is:

```
SELECT `model`.`round_id`, `model`.`type_id` FROM `database`.`model` AS `X` WHERE `X`.`Round_id` = '1'
```

**If I make this query to the database returns two values** ​​but cakephp returns only one:

```
Array ( [1] => 2 )
```

i do not know that may be going

Comment: why does find(list) not work for you?

Comment: Now you just totally changed your question. As you can see the "key" is "1" (round_id) and the "value" is "2" (type_id). So it returns TWO values, not one.

Comment: @mark does not work for me and I dont know the reason

Comment: If you are overwhelmed by find(list) just use find(all) and manually interate over your result.

Comment: yes @mark but it is assumed that the function should return all ids separately, or no?

Comment: no, find list returns always a list (key + value row). use find(all) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

```
$ids = $this->Model->find('list', array('fields' => array('id')));
```

if you really need the 0 based integer keys, you can still do:

```
$ids = array_values($ids);
```

but that is not necessary IMO.

**Update:**

After your question update the whole meaning of your question itself changed:

If you specify only id, they keys and values will both be filled with it.
Using `'fields' => array('round_id', 'type_id')` you have round_id filling the keys, and type_id filling the values for find(list).

find(list) returns always a list (key + value row). If you don't want that use find(all) then.

Comment: I edited the question because I also thought about that but it does not work, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was wrong with the method list, thanks!